# add custom method to jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I do something like:

```
$("#some_div").dialog("doSomething");
```

And what that method should do is to add an extra icon in the titlebar

**EDIT 1**: I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642652/702353): the method gets called but I can't access the dialog object (maybe I'm doing something wrong)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I've updated my question to show what I've tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is what I did:

```
//in a separate js file
$.ui.dialog.prototype.showExtraButton = function()
{
    this.uiDialogTitlebar.append("<a role='button' class='ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-icon-extra'><span class='ui-icon'></span></a>");
}

//call it this way
$("#some_div").dialog("showExtraButton");

//css
.ui-dialog-titlebar-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-icon-extra span
{
    display: block;
    background-image: url(../path_to_img/button_extra.png)!important;
}
```

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642652/702353) by Langdon, along with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10902542/702353) by Kevin B gave me the answer on how to resolve my problem

**UPDATE 2014-01-03**

TIL about [$.widget()](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/), so here is another implementation of the same thing

```
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog,
{
    showExtraButton: function()
    {
        this.uiDialogTitlebar.append("<a role='button' class='ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-icon-extra'><span class='ui-icon'></span></a>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Side Note: Try separating form from function. Unless that anchor (that's wrapping the `<span class='ui-icon'></span>` serves a specific purpose, you're probably better off without it (i.e.: you can use a different tag instead).

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're adding an icon to the title bar I would suggest applying a class to that dialog box and styling it with CSS. Example:

```
$( "#some_div" ).dialog({ dialogClass: "someClass" });
```

If you'd still like to add a custom method, here's what the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog) says:

Supply a callback function to handle the create event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   create: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Bind to the create event by type: dialogcreate.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogcreate", function(event, ui) { 
    ... 
});
```

Comment: the "create" approach is for use that event when the dialog is created. I need to add an icon at run time.

Comment: Should have clarified that in your question - glad you solved your problem.